# Restore generic video driver

Tags: drivers, ati, restore

i've installed video drivers from The official site support of AMD/nVidia, ive got an ATI sapphire 3850HD. When i reboot The top bar of Evert windows is disappear and the left bar of ubuntu its disappear to. How can i restore my old generic driver?

Answer (score 1):

Running this should do it: `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` then reboot